# Updating a string in solidity via String manipulation or storing a new string?

Tags: ethereum

In my smart contract I need to update a certain string storing a value of fixed 64 characters length to a new string when certain conditions are met.

However from research it shows that both string manipulation and string storing is costly.
So what would be the best way to achieve this among:

1. Using a util library that allows string manipulation of copying
2. Deleting the older value and storing a new one from a function to the same variable
3. creating a mapping and storing the string in increments, i.e leaving the old string as is and storing to a new location.

I couldn't find a single article or site which says what's the better way of doing this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.